# How to use the 4-class NER tagger of CoreNLP?

Tags: command-line-interface, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using [Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) to do some nlp tasks. More specifically, I'm using this command

```
java -mx1g -cp "./stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -outputFormat conll -file my_file.txt
```

to perform ner tagging (plus some other tasks like tokenizing and pos tagging).
With this, the NER tags I obtain include: DATE, NUMBER, TIME, DURATION, ORDINAL, MONEY.

I would like to use the Stanford NER tagger that only tags with: PERSON, ORGANIZATION, LOCATION, MISC, and O.

How I should modify my bash command above to indicate that I want the 4-tags NER classifier ?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a property file in the model jar file.(for chinese version it is StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties)
You can change the NER model file in the property file